# CFBundleVersion Not Matching

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm attempting to upload an application to apple, and i keep receiving this error:

*ERROR ITMS-90345: "Metadata/Info.plist Mismatch. The value for bundle_version in the metadata.xml file does not match the value for CFBundleVersion in 'App Name Here' [Payload/App Name.app]."*

I can't seem to edit my CFBundleVersion in my plist so it matches, any thoughts???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can click on your project file, then click on your target, and change in the general tab the version of your app.

What is important is that you should not have any spaces in the version, if the version that you specified in iTunesConnect is also without spaces.

I did get the same error because I had a trailing space in the version which was difficult to detect.

Answer (score 9):

I just got the same problem. Looks like app store compares **CFBundleVersion** with the last one. The current one should be higher.

Example: current 2022.06.14 will be rejected if there is another build say 2022.07 already in the TestFlight.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an app extension, make sure that the build number in the extension target is the same as in the app target.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your project file(info.plist) then ensure that the MinimumOSVersion is either same as the previously submitted apps or higher. In my case, I lowered the MinimumOSVersion of my app accidentally. So after I changed it back to what it was before I was able to submit my app to Itunes Connect using application loader. You can also check for spaces in the version string if you wish and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION after you change MARKETING_VERSION, or you can change CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION to 1 (CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION=1)

Comment: Please provide clearer answer with screenshots and steps to follow to reach.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).